# After main thread call pthread_exit, it turn into zombie.something wrong?

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, proc

I want to enumerate threads of specific process using /proc/[pid]/task/.but in proc man pages, it said:

> In a multithreaded process, the contents of the /proc/[pid]/task directory are not available if the main thread has already terminated (typically by calling pthread_exit(3)).

then I write some code,

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* PrintHello(void* data){
  pthread_t tid = (pthread_t)data;
  int rc;

  rc = pthread_join(tid, NULL);
  if(rc){
    exit(1);
  } else{
    printf("Hello from new thread %d - got %d\n", pthread_self(), data);
    sleep(180);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
  }
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int rc;
  pthread_t thread_id;
  thread_t tid;

  tid = pthread_self();
  printf("\nmain thread(%d) ", tid); 

  rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, PrintHello, (void*)tid);
  if(rc){
    printf("\n ERROR: return code from pthread_create is %d \n", rc);
    exit(1);
  }
  sleep(1);
  printf("\n Created new thread (%d) ... \n", thread_id);
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

after the main thread call pthread_exit(), it turn to zombie. and the /proc/[pid]/task directory remains, but /proc/[pid]/maps is empty.

```
$ ./a.out & 
 main thread(164759360) 
 Created new thread (164755200) ... 
Hello from new thread 164755200 - got 164759360

$ ps auwx |  grep a.out
spyder    5408  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/0    Zl+  10:27   0:00 [a.out] <defunct>
spyder    5412  0.0  0.0 109400   896 pts/1    S+   10:27   0:00 grep --color=auto a.out

$ ls /proc/5408/task/
5408  5409
$ cat /proc/5408/maps 
$ cat /proc/5408/status
Name:   a.out
State:  Z (zombie)
Tgid:   5408
Pid:    5408
....
$ cat /proc/5409/maps 
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 fd:02 2752690                            /home/spyder/a.out
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 fd:02 2752690                            /home/spyder/a.out
018cb000-018ec000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
3dcf000000-3dcf020000 r-xp 00000000 fd:01 139203                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.15.so
3dcf21f000-3dcf220000 r--p 0001f000 fd:01 139203                         /usr/lib64/ld-2.15.so
....
```

Something wrong?

Comment: I think the documentation is just outdated. Ideally both `task` and `maps` would still be available, but consider yourself fortunate that at least `task` exists. And don't rely on this working on older kernels since it probably doesn't...

Comment: your main process first quit, then your child process quit.But main process quit will cause that all his child processes quit.This a conflict.

Comment: @MYMNeo I dont think you get the point.first it's main thread not main process, and i only use pthread_exit to quit main thread, and other threads continue as expected. my question is why main threads turn to zombie.

Answer (score 1):

You've got this all backwards. Your function which executes on the `PrintHello` function is joining on the `main()` thread, when it should be the other way around:

In your `main()` thread/function, you should be calling:

```
(void)pthread_join(thread_id, NULL);
```

In short, `pthread_join()` means "wait until the thread with and identify of 'thread_id' is done before I do anything else". Your code is basically saying:

1. Start the main() program logic
2. Create a thread, do some printf() and sleep() stuff, then exit the entire program
3. At the same time, you've created a thread that is not going to do anything until main() dies
4. When main() dies, it hoses everything anyways, so there's no chance for the `PrintHello()` thread to close off gracefully, as the join() call will likely fail

You probably meant to do this (please note the extra comments):

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void* PrintHello(void* data){
  pthread_t tid = (pthread_t)data;

  //pthread_join(tid, NULL);  //WRONG
  printf("Hello from new thread %d - I was launched by thread number: %d\n", pthread_self(), data);
  sleep(180); //Sleep for 3 minutes, for no reason really
  pthread_exit(NULL); //All done in this thread
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int rc;
  pthread_t thread_id;
  long int tid;

  tid = pthread_self();

  rc = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, PrintHello, (void*)tid);
  if(rc) {
    printf("\n ERROR: return code from pthread_create is %d; Thread probably didn't get created\n", rc);
    exit(1);
  }
  sleep(1); //Sleep, for no reason
  printf("\n Created new thread (%d) ... Now let's wait for it to finish\n", thread_id);
  pthread_join(thread_id, NULL); //Wait for the child thread to finish it's work
  return 0; //All done!
}
```

If my assumptions are correct, please indicate this is the case and I can make some further corrections. Good luck!

Comment: yes, it's the normal way, but according to the manual, main threads can call pthread_exit to quit. And other threads will run just fine, after that, /proc/[pid]/task is not available. But my example code shows, the `task` directory is fine. but main threads turn into zombie thread. As R.. says, maybe the document is outdated.

Comment: @spyder If you want to exit the main thread while letting the created thread(s) continue, you have to _detach_ the threads you create. See e.g. [`pthread_detach`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_detach).

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding on how the pthreads library works, I believe that the reason for the zombie thread is that joining *normally* with the main thread would throw away its resources and since the main thread returns a status (through the return of the main function) that could and in some cases is expected to be consumed by the parent process (i.e., through the use of wait), this thread cannot be completely destroyed until the thread group has exited entirely (i.e., that the whole process has exited). If it was somehow allowed to return the value of the pthread_exit call to the parent process then the parent would think that the child had exited which wouldn't be true, since the *PrintHello* function would be still running.